# Rails 3 or arel chain/merge SQL conditions conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Is there a way in Rails 3 to merge record conditions conditionally without doing string or array merging?

For example:

```
    conditions = #?    
    if !params[:x].blank?
      # add a condition
    end
    if user.role?(:admin)
      # add a condition
    end
    if params[:y]
     # add a condition
    end
    etc
    result = Record.where(xx).group(:id).order(some_var) 
    # xx would merge all then group and order
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy:

```
# oh, the joy of lazy evaluation...
result = Record.where(true) # I'd like to do Record.all, but that fetches the records eagerly!
result = result.where("...") if params[:x].present?
result = result.where("...") if user.role?(:admin)
result = result.where("...") if params[:y].present?
```

By the way, don't try this in `irb`: the "print" part of "read-eval-print" will force evaluation of the record set.

**EDIT:** I just figured out that instead of `Record.where(true)`, you could use `Record.scoped`. This won't work in Rails 4, though.

Comment: No prob. tenderlove's `arel` library makes things like this possible -- I think that library is a real masterpiece.